# Update table record in generalized form using lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Here is my code which update record of `tableBrand` table successfully but I want to update my record in much more normalized form.

```
public bool Update(tableBrand brand)
{                
    if (brand == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("brand");
    }
    tableBrand tmpBrand = Get(brand.BrandID);

    if (tmpBrand != null)
    {
        tmpBrand.BrandName = brand.BrandName;
        plaDatabaseEntities.SaveChanges();
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Note:**
Here is only two column BrandName and BrandID so we can update it normally.But suppose there is
25 numbers of columns in one table then we will have to assign value to each and every column in as a manually way.but I don't want to update my table records as above way.I want to update table record
as below code and description.And here `Get(brand.BrandID)` return an object of tableBrand.

```
public bool Update(tableBrand brand)
{        
   if (brand == null)
   {
       throw new ArgumentNullException("brand");
   }
   tablebrand tmpbrand = Get(brand.brandID);

   if (tmpbrand != null)
   {
       tmpbrand = brand;
       plaDatabaseEntities.SaveChanges();
   }
   return true;
}
```

As I know that if we want to update any record of table then we must have that record id to fire a query and fetch data from database. In above code I am able to fetch record from database using of brand.brandID. But here I want to assign tmpbrand object like this `tmpbrand = brand;` as above but on that time the problem is that `tmpbrand` is being over write  here some I am not being able to update my record as above manner.

I hope so there is a way with lambda expression if we get all field of `brand` object except of `brandID` and assign all filed to `tmpbrand` except of `brandID` then I can solve this problem but I am not getting it's answer how to get all filed from `brand` object except of `brandID` and assign all filed to `tmpbrand` except of `brandID` using lambda expression or Linq.

If somebody have solution of this problem then please help me...

Comment: How brand object was created? Did you read it from a database, if so how?

Comment: brand is a object of tableBrand.

Comment: Is tableBrand a class created by you or was it generated automatically by Visual Studio?

Comment: it is generated automatically by Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Linq To Sql but I think that you have 2 options:

1. *brand* object is still attached to the data context when *Update* method is called. If it is true, you don't have to copy its values to the another object. Linq To Sql tracks changes for you. See also this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399339%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
2. *brand* object is **not** attached to the data context when *Update* method is called. In this case you have to use *[Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548778%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)* method and then save changes. Again you don't have to copy values from one object to the another. See also this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244096/what-does-linq-to-sql-tablet-attach-do).